# Onesignal GDPR changes not registering the device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

Onesignal not registering the device when i tried out the below steps for Onesignal new GDPR changes & i don’t know is correct or not.

**STEP 1:** In Application onCreate

```
if(!OneSignal.userProvidedPrivacyConsent()) {
 OneSignal.setRequiresUserPrivacyConsent(true);
}
```

**STEP 2:** i will set provideUserConsent(true) when user accept the terms

**STEP 3:** after user accepts terms i will startInit() the OneSignal method

```
 OneSignal.startInit(this)
     .setNotificationReceivedHandler(new OneSignalNotificationReceivedHandler())
     .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new OneSignalNotificationOpenedHandler())
     .init();
```

When Following the above steps i will getting Log Message like this

> 05-23 11:19:21.790 22460-22460/com.example.app V/OneSignal: OneSignal
>   SDK initialization delayed, user privacy consent is set to required
>   for this application.
>
> 05-23 11:19:21.795 22460-22460/com.example.app
>   W/OneSignal: Method idsAvailable() was called before the user provided
>   privacy consent. Your application is set to require the user's privacy
>   consent before the OneSignal SDK can be initialized. Please ensure the
>   user has provided consent before calling this method. You can check
>   the latest OneSignal consent status by calling
>   OneSignal.userProvidedPrivacyConsent()

In OneSignal Dashboard am getting message like this

> Google Play services library initialization error. Check for
>   conflicting plugins and make sure "com.google.android.gms.version" is
>   in your AndroidManifest.xml. Check the logcat for more details.

but i included all necessary details in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must have been a mistake.

`setRequiresUserPrivacyConsent(true)` must be called before OneSignal is initialized.

Example:

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // Prevents OneSignal from sending any data until provideUserConsent` is called.
    OneSignal.setRequiresUserPrivacyConsent(true);

    // OneSignal Initialization
    OneSignal.startInit(this)
        .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
        .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
        .init();
}

public void onUserTappedProvidePrivacyConsent(View v) {
    // will initialize the OneSignal SDK and enable push notifications
    OneSignal.provideUserConsent(true);
}
```

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk#section--setrequiresuserprivacyconsent-